# PHP Library for aggregation of my Social Media Streams

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, social-networking

i'm looking for a library which can merge all my social media streams to one stream. Sure I could do this own my own by using all the custom apis of the sites, but i don't like to reinvent the wheel so I appreciate any helpful hint.
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Nils

Edit:

I just found this jQuery Plugin: http://christianv.github.com/jquery-lifestream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [Storytlr](http://storytlr.org/) a try. It is an open source project that will pull in posts from a number of SM sites and has a plugin system to support additional ones.

Comment: thank you, this looks very promissing.

Answer (score 1):

Most social media apps have RSS/Atom feeds. Use a library like [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) to consume and aggregate them.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont like this solution. Facebook for example changed the URL to your social feed way to often in the last years.